# Como fazer filtro JS somente com números e letras (sem caracteres especiais)

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso de ajuda para fazer uma função onde eu coloco um código para pesquisar e ela me mostra o resultado. O problema é que, atualmente, só traz o resultado se eu colocar exatamente como está no JSON.

Ex.: se eu pesquisar "9 190 087 006" ele vai me trazer a linha que está esse código, mas se eu colocar o mesmo código "9190087006" (sem espaços), ele não encontra.

Podem me ajudar a melhorar o código para que independente de haver algum caractere especial ele consiga trazer os resultados, considerando somente os números e letras para fazer a pesquisa?

```html
<textarea id='txt' style="height: 200">
9 190 087 006
9190087006
13067/5
130675
VR-B190
VR B190
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick='limpar()'>Clear</button>
<button onclick='render()'>Pesquisa</button>
<!-- <input type="" name="" id='pesq'> -->

<div id="lista"></div>

<script>
    
    x = [

{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9 190 087 006"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9-190-085-001"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9.190.087.011"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"13067/5"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"2500216"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"130216"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"IK420HD"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"VR-B190"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"VRB190"}},
{"Codigo":"T003","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"IB305"}},
{"Codigo":"T003","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9 190 083 002"}},
{"Codigo":"T003","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"1197 BE3 002"}}

]

    function pesquisa(valor){
        // valor = this.value
        
        resultados = []
        for(i of x){

            reg = new RegExp(valor,"g")

            if(valor == i.Cod[' Marca'].match(reg)){
                resultados.push(i)
            }
        }
        return resultados
        // console.log(resultados)
        // lista.innerHTML = resultados
    }

    function add(str){
        j = []
        json1 = pesquisa(str)
        div = document.createElement("div")
        div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json1)
        lista.appendChild(div)
    }

    function render(){
        t = txt.value.split("\n")
        for(o of t){
            add(o)
        }
    }
    render()

    function limpar(){
        lista.innerHTML = ""
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloquei um trecho no if, basicamente o que fez, eliminando os caracteres especiais em uma das condições:

```
if(valor == i.Cod[' Marca'].replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'').match(reg) || valor == i.Cod[' Marca'].match(reg))
```

Mantive o que fez no `or` pois somente no regex ele não retorna com os caracteres especiais, desta forma, retorna ambos.

Fiddle do resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/w3jq8g2t/

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução para este problema é criar strings novas sem esses tais caracteres especiais. Para isso, podemos usar uma regex como `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g`, que dá match em qualquer caracter que **não** seja letra ou número. Daí, usamos o `replace()` para trocar por um caracter vazio:

```html
<textarea id='txt' style="height: 200">
9 190 087 006
9190087006
13067/5
130675
VR-B190
VR B190
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick='limpar()'>Clear</button>
<button onclick='render()'>Pesquisa</button>
<!-- <input type="" name="" id='pesq'> -->

<div id="lista"></div>

<script>
    
    x = [

{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9 190 087 006"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9-190-085-001"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9.190.087.011"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"13067/5"}},
{"Codigo":"T001","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"2500216"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"130216"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"IK420HD"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"VR-B190"}},
{"Codigo":"T002","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"VRB190"}},
{"Codigo":"T003","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"IB305"}},
{"Codigo":"T003","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"9 190 083 002"}},
{"Codigo":"T003","Marca":"AAAAAA","Cod":{" Marca":"1197 BE3 002"}}

]

    function pesquisa(valor){
        // valor = this.value
        
        resultados = []
        for(i of x){

            const formattedInput = valor.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
            const formattedCodMarca = i.Cod[' Marca'].replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');

            if(formattedInput === formattedCodMarca){
                resultados.push(i)
            }
        }
        return resultados
        // console.log(resultados)
        // lista.innerHTML = resultados
    }

    function add(str){
        j = []
        json1 = pesquisa(str)
        div = document.createElement("div")
        div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json1)
        lista.appendChild(div)
    }

    function render(){
        t = txt.value.split("\n")
        for(o of t){
            add(o)
        }
    }
    render()

    function limpar(){
        lista.innerHTML = ""
    }

</script>
```

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo amigo